# Android : Animating TextView having Long Text to display

Tags: textview, android

I am working on Android Project developing on Eclipse Framework.Here I want to scroll long text on screen , for the same I have used Animation class.It is working all right as per my requirement,
For the reference I am sharing my code here :

```
    TextView tt = new TextView (this);
    tt.setText("Welcome Here is my very long text to display.But only some part of text is getting displayed, not the entire text.Please provide me the solution so that entire text should be displayed on the screen");
    tt.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.valueOf("MARQUEE"));
    tt.setTextSize(40);
    tt.setSingleLine(true);

    //here actual_scr_width = device screen width
    //here actual_scr_height = device screen height

    if(direction.equalsIgnoreCase("left"))
    {
         Animation animationToLeft = new TranslateAnimation(actual_scr_width, -actual_scr_width, 0, 0);
         animationToLeft.setDuration(12000);
         animationToLeft.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
         animationToLeft.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
         tt.setAnimation(animationToLeft);
    }
    else if(direction.equalsIgnoreCase("right"))
    {
         Animation animationToLeft = new TranslateAnimation(-actual_scr_width, actual_scr_width, 0, 0);
         animationToLeft.setDuration(12000);
         animationToLeft.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
         animationToLeft.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
         tt.setAnimation(animationToRight);
    }
```

but only the problem is that when I am having long text to scroll as marquee, it displays only certain portion of text,not the entire text.Can you please suggest me the best appropriate solution so that entire text can be scrolled as marquee ?
Waiting for reply...
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got the solution for above problem. So in order to overcome the above problem, I applied different approach. I am sharing this with you all, so that it might also solve your purpose. What I did is that, I have used Webview, and then loaded the html page on that by using its loadurl method.

```
Webview wv = new Webview();
wv.loadurl("SampleMarquee.html");
```

Through html you can easily implement the marrqee. Here in html, there is no restriction the length of text. Then finally add this webview to your main layout so our purpose is fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in your code Even you remove animation part it can working as same marquee functionality. try to animate text alone not text box in you code.